# Power Automate Flow Save Failed with code 'InvalidVariableInitialization'

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, microsoft-flow, send-email

I've created a scheduled flow and added initialize variables to format how the data shows in my email notification. This works fine in my other flow - when a new item is created. But for this scheduled flow, and get items action, I'm getting the error:

> 'Flow save failed with code 'InvalidVariableInitialization' and message 'The variable action 'Initialize_variable_4' of type 'InitializeVariable' cannot be nested in an action of type 'Apply_to_each_3'.'.

Is there a way to fix this? Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks so much!

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason for creating a variable inside apply to each action. It is best practice to create a variable at the start of the flow to avoid any errors. Try initializing variable at the start of the flow outside apply to each action. Let me know if it resolves this error message.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks for looking into this. I've actually created the variable outside but it's automatically adding it inside the apply to each action. I suspect it's probably because in the value field, I've added the 'Survey Feedback' from dynamic content.

Comment: Wait a minute, I am writing a answer with more explanation and easier/cleaner solution without using apply to each action and variables.

Comment: Check my answer given below. Let me know if it works for you or if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I've tried the given instructions but I'm probably doing something wrong because the survey feedback data showing in my email notification includes other items survey feedback data too :(

Comment: Are you trying to get surve feedback from single list item? You Have To manage which items to Bring using get items action

Comment: Yes, I only need to show the survey feedback from single list item. If I don't add the select/compose operations, it only shows the data of the item that are due to send the email reminder.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your flow trigger and get items action/conditions? What are the conditions to get the items from list in scheduled flow? Can you explain your requirements in detail? Generally, if you want to fetch single list item & item ID is known to you, you should use **Get item** action instead of **Get items** action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145480/discussion-between-gen-c-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this and I can't seem to find the option to add a screenshot here. I have a scheduled flow that looks at the items in the list where the acknowledgement hasn't been sent to the customer (Actual Acknowledgement Date is null) and it will send a reminder email to the user 1 day before the due date. This runs on a daily basis from Mondays to Fridays.

Comment: You can Edit your original question and then attach screenshot. Are you sending separate email for each list item? If yes, why were you collecting survey feedback for all items from get items action in single variable using apply to each? If that is the case, you can try this: recurrence trigger > initialize variable with no/blank value > get items action > apply to each on get items "value" array > inside apply to each (**set variable** action for survey feedback > compose > send email action).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I've attached screenshots of my flow trigger and get items action/conditions. I'm getting an error in the compose action. InvalidTemplate, Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue'. Please help.

Comment: Is Survey Feedback column value empty for any of the list items/rows?

Comment: Nope, they are all populated.

Comment: Oh it is throwing error related to `oldValue` in replace function syntax meaning it is related to your `varLineBreak` variable.

Comment: I've added 0 in the initial value of varLineBreak initialize variable and the error disappeared but the survey feedback data still has the incorrect format. :(

Comment: Are you using compose action inside apply to each action? Also why are you using 2 apply to each actions on the same get items results? Can you show the screenshot of survey feedback data in the list if possible? Are these values only on one line or spanned over multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, the compose action is inside the apply to each action. I've created a new flow with 1 apply to each action only but still the same issue. :( I've attached screenshots of the new flow and the list. The values were spanned over multiple lines.

Comment: If those are already entered on new lines, do you explicitly need to add new line character again in the flow expressions? If those are coming properly with new lines from SharePoint outputs but not showing correctly in outlook emails. You can try adding this CSS to email body: `white-space: pre;`

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of variables should always occur at the start of the flow. If you create a variable after the trigger action of the flow, it can result in errors.

When defining a variable inside an `Apply to each` loop, it's best practice to make the variable global and use it inside the loop in a manner that it gets iterated as intended.

In your case move action `Initialize Variable 4` to the top after trigger and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Pradip, thanks for looking into this. I tried adding the Initialize Variable 4 to the top but it's automatically putting it inside an Apply to each loop. It's probably because I'm using a  dynamic content.

Comment: @Gen_C You can have dynamic content in action without any issues. Just initialize a variable with an empty value at the beginning, and within your "Apply to each" action, use the "Set Variable" action to set the value as dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you are trying to initialize a variable inside apply to each action which is not supported in Power Automate.

It is recommended and a best practice to initialize a variable at the start of the flow to avoid any errors.

So, try initializing all your variables at the start of the flow after flow trigger before any other actions.

---

If you want a cleaner flow without using any variables and apply to each action, you can use flow as shown below:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

In Select action:

```
@item()?['SurveyFeedback']
```

Where `SurveyFeedback` is the internal name of my SharePoint column. Follow this to find the internal name of your SharePoint column: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

In Compose action:

```
@{join(body('Select_-_Collect_Survey_feedbacks'),'<br/>')}
```

**Output Email**:

[image]

**Note**: You can also avoid **Compose** action and use expression to add `<br/>` directly in email body as well.